# Could not find or load main class when using JUnit 5 in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

I am currently facing problems when using JUnit 5 in VSCode.

I noticed that as soon as the "junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0-M1.jar" is in my library folder within my project I can run my tests but I can not run my main method any more ("Error: Could not find or load main class"). As soon as I remove the .jar I can immediately run it again.

The problem also occurs when I use the default project with no-build tools.

I created a simple test class and let the .jar file automatically download via the "Testing" explorer (enable Java Tests Button). Now that the .jar file is downloaded, the tests work but the main method doesn't. If I remove the .jar out of the folder, the main method works again but obviously the tests aint.
[image: Main class and project folder]

[image: Test class]

[image: settings.json file]

[image: Error Message]

Any solutions so I can run both? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your project, here are a few workarounds that might help:

1. Reload VS Code and run **F1** -> `Clean the java language server workspace`.
2. Add the `mainClass` and `sourcePaths` configuration in your `launch.json` file.
3. Check your folder/file name and make sure the file path is in plain English.
4. This can also cause problems if you have the **Code Runner** extension installed. You can try to uninstall it, then **F1** -> `Clean the java language server workspace`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you Answere. Unfortunately, none of your steps worked. I found out that this problem also occurs even when I use the default "Hello World" Java Project. Again, as soon as the .jar file is in the lib folder, I can not run the main any longer, so I think there is nothing wrong with my project.

Comment: terribly sorry. But I put the `junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0-M1.jar` file you mentioned into the `lib` folder and then run the code, [no problem appears on my machine](https://imgur.com/a/j6NrH0R). Can you provide more information so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I updated my post. Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: I am really sorry. I tried following your steps, but it all [works fine](https://imgur.com/a/w3bDdWq) on my machine. 
I see your error message indicating `ClassNotFound`, is the `App.class` file generated in your `bin` folder? 
Try running the code using the `javac` and `java` commands in the terminal and see if it gives an error?

Comment: Hi, any update on the question? If it has not been resolved, can you provide your process for creating the project?

Comment: No, I haven‘t solved the problem yet. It must be a problem with my VS Code since I followed the exact same steps as it is shown in the Guide on the VS Code website or in multiple Youtube videos.

Comment: Well, if you have tried reinstalling [the latest version](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68) of vscode and it didn't work. Please submit your issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/new).